# How can Python traverse the file directory to let the program know how to traverse to the last file

Tags: python

How can Python traverse the file directory so that the program knows to traverse to the last file?
I've tried my best. It's no good.
There are several folders in a directory, each folder has dozens of subfolders, each folder has two files.
I can only identify the last file very rigidly.

```
def openfile(inputdir):
global total,namebefor,nameafter,array
file = os.listdir(inputdir)
for fi in file:
    fidir = os.path.join(inputdir, fi)
    if os.path.isfile(fidir) and os.path.splitext(fidir)[1] in [".CSV"]:
        news = fidir.split("\\")
        nowname = news[-3]
        namebefor = nowname
        if namebefor == nowname:
            if namebefor !=nameafter:
                if nameafter != namebefor and array!=[]:
                    print(nameafter)
                    print(array)
                    print(int(total / 2))
                    array = []
                    total = 0
                else:
                    array.append(fidir)
                    total = total+1
            else:
                array.append(fidir)
                total = total + 1
                if nameafter == namebefor and array[-1].split("\\")[-1] == "9.CSV":
                    print(array)
                    print(nameafter)
                    print(int(total / 2))
                    array = []
                    total = 0
        nameafter = nowname
    elif os.path.isdir(fidir):
            openfile(fidir)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfdoQ.png)

If I don't use "and array [-1]. split ("\") [-1]="9.CSV":"
Under this condition, you can't print out the path of YD-4. But it's too rigid. If my last one is not 9.CSV, I have to change the conditions constantly.

Comment: You could try to create a tree by using `os.walk`, on each node you could put all the files in a list, a file can also be a folder so each folder can have it's own tree. From there you could easily traverse the tree you created and get the last element in the lists you created on the leaves of the tree. Also defining the last file would depend on how you sort the lists, (date of creation, alphabetical order, whatever you want)

Comment: Os. walk I have tried, I will add my code. But the result is that the final "YD-4" directory cannot be exported.

Comment: Thank you very much. I seem to understand. It's just been tested and some progress has been made.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code hereafor dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(".."):
for filepath in filenames:
    if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(dirpath, filepath))[1] in [".CSV"]:
        nowpath = os.path.join(dirpath, filepath)
        total += 1
        nowname =dirpath.split("\\")[-2]
        namebefor=nowname
        if namebefor==nowname:
            if nameafter!=namebefor:
                if namebefor!=nameafter and array!=[]:
                    print("%s" % array)
                    array = []
                    total = 0
                    array.append(nowpath)
                    total += 1
                else:
                    array.append(nowpath)
            else:
                array.append(nowpath)
            nameafter=nowname
        # print(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(dirpath, filepath))[0])
        # print(os.path.join(dirpath, filepath))
```